# Initialising random number generator in Matlab

Tags: matlab, random

In Matlab one can use `rng('default');` to initialize the random number generator.

Does this only hold for the current function or for the whole session?

Second, I only want to initialize the random number generator in a specific function. Before and after that specific function the not initialized random number generator should be used. How can this be done?

Edit: There is an additional problem. I want to use the cvpartition function which internally uses random numbers but I cannot pass a RandStream object to the function. How can I use a initialized random number generator for the cvpartition function?

Comment: Daniel answered your second question.  As for the first question, `rng` uses a global state as he mentioned which means that wherever you use `rng`, if it's in a function or outside in the Command Prompt, once you call it with a certain seed, that seed is used for the entire session. Further calls to `rand*` functions will use that seed regardless of where those functions get called (i.e. in a local function, command prompt, etc.).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a [`RandStream`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/randstream.html) object instead, it allows you to choose what you want, for example creating one object for each function you use.

`rng` always uses a global state.

Comment: There is an additional problem. I want to use the cvpartition function which internally uses random numbers but I cannot pass a RandStream object to the  function. How can I use a initialized random number generator for the cvpartition function?